# How to take a screenshot with Selenium in python in the actual moment of the page?

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot, pyautogui, capture

I'm trying to take a screenshot with Selenium of my project in python, the thing is that Selenium only takes the screenshot when the page loads, and I would like to take it in the moment after it loads. Here's the code I have.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8050/")
driver.refresh()
S = lambda X:driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
driver.set_window_size(S('Width'), S('Height'))
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot('prueba.png')
pyautogui.screenshot()
```

Comment: Why not wait for the visibility of an element?

Comment: Yeah, wait for the page to finish loading, then take the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly use PyAutoGui instead,
you could just use the `pyautogui.screenshot()` function
and if you need a specific region you could just use:
`pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1,y1, x2, y2))`

this should be fast enough for what you asked.

if you need more info click [here](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html)